# Replace image in reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

Suppose I have two very similar images I want to display in succession (say first is a photo and the second one the same photo with some area highlighted). I'd like to avoid a transition animation and just have the second image replace the first image. Is this possible with `reveal.js`?

Setting `data-transition="none"` doesn't work very well because the previous slide still retains its animation.

Answer (score 12):

Reveal.js does not have any direct method by itself for doing of what is being asked. However, it can be done using a `div` container and the [fragment](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#fragments) feature of reveal.js. The container includes the images, which are absolutely positioned within it, and because of that it has to have fix dimensions.

The following piece of html displays the first image and on the next slide the second image on top of the first one.

```
<section>
<h1>Slide 1</h1>
<div style="position:relative; width:640px; height:480px; margin:0 auto;">
  <img class="fragment" width="640" height="480" src="img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" />
  <img class="fragment" width="640" height="480" src="img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" />
</div>
</section>
```

While this piece of html displays the first image and on the next slide the first image fades out and the second image fades in instead.

```
<section>
<h1>Slide 2</h1>
<div style="position:relative; width:640px; height:480px; margin:0 auto;">
  <img class="fragment fade-out" data-fragment-index="0" width="640" height="480" src="img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" />
  <img class="fragment fade-in" data-fragment-index="0" width="640" height="480" src="img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" />
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: the use of `position:absolute` messes up PDF exports as for reveal 3

Answer (score 12):

reveal.js 4.0 introduces a new `r-stack` class that makes it easier to stack elements on top of each other.

```html
<div class="r-stack">
  <img class="fragment" src="https://placekitten.com/450/300" width="450" height="300">
  <img class="fragment" src="https://placekitten.com/300/450" width="300" height="450">
  <img class="fragment" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" width="400" height="400">
</div>
```

The above example fades in images on top of each other. If you want to only show one image at a time you'll need to use slightly different fragment settings.

```html
<div class="r-stack">
  <img class="fragment current-visible" src="...">
  <img class="fragment current-visible" src="...">
  <img class="fragment" src="...">
</div>
```

You can see examples of how this works in the reveal.js docs https://revealjs.com/layout/#stack

Comment: Thanks to @hakim for adding this feature, and for the great summary of it here!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to use Javascript. With this code you can not only replace images, but any content.

It is important to apply the classes `content-target` and `content-source`. It is also important to use the `display: none;` style.

The html could look like:

```
<section>
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <div class="content-target"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div class="content-source fragment" data-fragment-index="0">
            <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-source fragment" data-fragment-index="1">
            <ul>
                <li>List item 1</li>
                <li>List item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content-source fragment" data-fragment-index="2">
            <img src="path/to/another/image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now we add a function `fadeContent()` and call it every time `fragmentshown` or `fragmenthidden` is triggered.

```
function fadeContent($el, back=false) {
    // If we go back, choose previous element, otherwise current element
    $new = (back ? $el.prev() : $el);
    if($new.length == 0) {
        $text = $el.parent().siblings('.content-target');
        $text.fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        $text = $new.parent().siblings('.content-target');
        $text.hide(0, function() {
            $text.html($new.html());
            $text.fadeIn(300);
        });
    }
}

Reveal.addEventListener('fragmentshown', function(event) {
    // Get first fragment which has "content-source" class
    var $el = $($(event.fragments).filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass('content-source')
    })[0]);

    // Show content
    if ($el.hasClass('content-source'))
        fadeContent($el);
});

Reveal.addEventListener('fragmenthidden', function(event) {
    // Get first fragment which has "content-source" class
    var $el = $($(event.fragments).filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass('content-source')
    })[0]);

    // Hide element
    if ($el.hasClass('content-source'))
        fadeContent($el, back=true);
});
```

Since we have just extended the *fragment* functionality, we can still use the `data-fragment-index` attribute and change the order.

The solution can easily be optimized/customized.

Comment: I've updated and improved the answer, can you try it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify two transitions, for entering and for leaving, thus the following works but has a glitch (image flicker when appearing) :

```
<section data-transition="slide none">
  <img src="timeline2.a.svg">
</section>
<section data-transition="none">
  <img src="timeline2.b.svg">
</section>
<section data-transition="none side">
  <img src="timeline2.c.svg">
</section>
```

Otherwise this may also be a solution, this is a bit different from what you want but is not bad :

```
<section data-transition="slide fade-out">
  <img src="timeline2.a.svg">
</section>
<section data-transition="fade-in fade-out">
  <img src="timeline2.b.svg">
</section>
<section data-transition="fade-in side">
  <img src="timeline2.c.svg">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me with nested fragments
outside of it i had a div with the class r-stack

```
<div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="1">
                    <img class="fragment fade-out" data-fragment-index="2" src="https://http.cat/418" width="50%">
                  </div>
                  <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="2">
                    <img class="fragment fade-out" data-fragment-index="3" src="https://http.cat/404" width="50%">
                  </div>
                  <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="3">
                    <img class="fragment fade-out" data-fragment-index="4" src="https://http.cat/100" width="50%">
                  </div>
                  <div class="fragment" data-fragment-index="4">
                    <img src="https://http.cat/420" width="50%">
                  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose, you are using `data-background` for displaying your photos, then you need to use `data-background-transition="none"` for the desired effect.